# Firefox Quantom, shift and f2 missing? Where do you type appCache validate?

Tags: firefox

In the new Firefox Quantum what's the equivilent of `shift+f2` to bring up the browser console?

I've seen [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI):

> The functions provided by the Developer Toolbar are available in the
>   Firefox Developer Tools Console Tab.

But 'appCache validate' doesn't seem to work there?

Answer (score 0):

The Developer Toolbar was removed completely from Firefox, and the functionality that it previously provided is no longer available from a command-line interface. Instead, you are supposed to use the Developer Tools directly to do what you previously did with commands inside the toolbar.

Application specific storage is visible in the “Storage” tab of the Developer Tools, which has support for various storage providers.

The [application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) being a deprecated functionality, does not appear to be supported within the Developer Tools anymore. If you need to access its items, you can visit `about:cache` though in order to look at the application cache items.